# Generate different gradle artifacts off single project or source

Tags: java, gradle

I have a huge legacy EAR project. Current build process uses Ant and I'm trying to convert to gradle.

The old Ant build uses a single source folder and everything is in there (EJB and WAR code together); then Ant uses different tasks to build EJB-JAR and WAR artifacts filtering by the package of interest (`my.web.*`  for the WAR and `my.ejb.*`  for the EJB).

It goes without saying that EJB and WAR heavily reference each other and I guess that's why they are compiled together even though separate artifacts are generated.

I have tried creating a parent EAR project, then separating `my.ejb.*`  in an EJB subproject as well as `my.web.*`  in a WAR subproject but gradle immediately complained about circular dependency and I haven't found a way around.

If above is not possible, then I am looking for recommendations on how to generate the EJB-JAR and WAR artifacts off the same codebase that would be compiled altogether, then include them in the EAR file as 'deploy' dependencies.

I have googled around but I am not very bright at gradle (obviously). Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are falling into the trap that many of us have when trying to convert an existing ant project to Gradle for the first time - you are thinking of things the same 'ol ant way.

Instead, let Gradle do the work for you and it will be easier and the resulting build.gradle file much smaller and more concise.

Thinking in terms of having a parent ear project and a separate war project is good thinking however. But, you should take advantage of the plugins Gradle has to offer to simplify the task of constructing the archives.

Use the 'ear plugin':
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/war_plugin.html

For example:

```
    apply plugin: 'ear'
    apply plugin: 'java'

    repositories { mavenCentral() }

    dependencies {
        // The following dependencies will be the ear modules and
        // will be placed in the ear root
        deploy project(':war')

        // The following dependencies will become ear libs and will
        // be placed in a dir configured via the libDirName property
        earlib group: 'log4j', name: 'log4j', version: '1.2.15', ext: 'jar'
    }

    ear {
        appDirName 'src/main/app'  // use application metadata found in this folder
        // put dependent libraries into APP-INF/lib inside the generated EAR
        libDirName 'APP-INF/lib'
        deploymentDescriptor {  // custom entries for application.xml:
    //      fileName = "application.xml"  // same as the default value
    //      version = "6"  // same as the default value
            applicationName = "customear"
            initializeInOrder = true
            displayName = "Custom Ear"  // defaults to project.name
            // defaults to project.description if not set
            description = "My customized EAR for the Gradle documentation"
    //      libraryDirectory = "APP-INF/lib"  // not needed, above libDirName setting does this
    //      module("my.jar", "java")  // won't deploy as my.jar isn't deploy dependency
    //      webModule("my.war", "/")  // won't deploy as my.war isn't deploy dependency
            securityRole "admin"
            securityRole "superadmin"
            withXml { provider -> // add a custom node to the XML
                provider.asNode().appendNode("data-source", "my/data/source")
            }
        }
    }
```

Then for your war, use the 'war plugin'. You can create the war as a separate project:

```
    configurations {
       moreLibs
    }

    repositories {
       flatDir { dirs "lib" }
       mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        compile module(":compile:1.0") {
            dependency ":compile-transitive-1.0@jar"
            dependency ":providedCompile-transitive:1.0@jar"
        }
        providedCompile "javax.servlet:servlet-api:2.5"
        providedCompile module(":providedCompile:1.0") {
            dependency ":providedCompile-transitive:1.0@jar"
        }
        runtime ":runtime:1.0"
        providedRuntime ":providedRuntime:1.0@jar"
        testCompile "junit:junit:4.12"
        moreLibs ":otherLib:1.0"
    }

    war {
        from 'src/rootContent' // adds a file-set to the root of the archive
        webInf { from 'src/additionalWebInf' } // adds a file-set to the WEB-INF dir.
        classpath fileTree('additionalLibs') // adds a file-set to the WEB-INF/lib dir.
        classpath configurations.moreLibs // adds a configuration to the WEB-INF/lib dir.
        webXml = file('src/someWeb.xml') // copies a file to WEB-INF/web.xml
    }
```

There is another helpful post on creating them as a single project, but that's definitely a bit more 'dicey':
https://discuss.gradle.org/t/single-project-with-jar-ejb-war-and-ear/5874

Comment: Thanks @pczeus. You're right, I'm probably in the trap of trying to do it the ant way but the reason of that is that when I have tried to do separate projects, I ran into the circular dependency issue with gradle. The ejb and war code are totally entangled so they need to be compiled together. In your example above, how would you include the EJB artifact?

Comment: Maybe this would be of use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3627791/how-do-i-create-several-ejb-jars-in-a-gradle-build-project . In general though, I just think of an ejb as a zip or a jar with specific manifest files and folder structure/contents. The war and ear plugins are really just providing syntactic sugar to provide a DSL for the known structure of that type of artifact. If it makes more sense to you, you could use the zip task and construct your own artifacts (jar,war,ear) by including/excluding the packages that yo need.

Comment: Thanks, again @pczeus, even though it's not the best solution, I think I will go for the suggestion you provided via https://discuss.gradle.org/t/single-project-with-jar-ejb-war-and-ear/5874